# Leaflet.js: Allow default drag/zoom options with HTML elements on top of map DIV

Tags: javascript, css, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using some javascript/css to 'draw' my own DIV and IMG elements on top of a Leaflet controlled map. I've managed to synchronise the pan and zoom movements so it looks like my own elements are really a part of the map in the background.

The only major backside: when I place the mouse over my custom HTML elements, the mouse icon changes from the 'move' icon to the default pointer, and it's not possible to drag or zoom the map.

Is there a way to give specific HTML elements on the page the drag and zoom controls like on the maptiles ? I do not want this on all elements though, some of them will need to offer a different kind of user interaction.

I haven't really explored the custom layer system of Leaflet yet. I assume that HTML elements of such custom layers will probably have those controls by default too. But there are some reasons why I would prefer to place HTML elements on top of the map, seperate from the Leaflet div.

Answer (score 3):

You should use L.control layers, which as you've described, are HTML elements embed inside the map and work as you've said.

They are easy to use and initialize by using L.Control.extend method.

Here its an example:

```
var self = this;
var newButton;
L.Control.currentPosition = L.Control.extend({
  onAdd: function (map) {
    //this method is called when this new control is added later to your map
    var className = 'your-custom-container-class',
    container = L.DomUtil.create('div', className);
    newButton = this._createButton(
      '', 'your-button-title',  'your-custom-button-class', 'your-button-id', container, this.newButtonFunction,  self);
    return container;
  },

  newButtonFunction: function(ev){

  },

  _createButton: function (html, title, className, id, container, fn, context) {
    var link = L.DomUtil.create('a', className, container);
    link.innerHTML = html;
    link.href = '#';
    link.title = title;
    link.id = id;
    var stop = L.DomEvent.stopPropagation;
    L.DomEvent
      .on(link, 'click', stop)
      .on(link, 'mousedown', stop)
      .on(link, 'dblclick', stop)
      .on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.preventDefault)
      .on(link, 'click', fn, context);
    return link;
  }
});

//finally add the new control to your map object
this.map.addControl(new L.Control.newButton());
```

You could do something like this ;)